# Hide decoded image in console (OkHttp)

Tags: android

is there a way to hide the OkHttp console log?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this `interceptor`:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging  = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
```

to your `OkHttpClient`